# libdc1394 package not available for Diamondback?

Tags: ros, ros-diamondback, bumblebee

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am new to ROS and Ubuntu environments... I have been trying to install bumblebee2 package for my system.. but it gives me the following error

```
      '[rosbuild] Building package bumblebee2
        Failed to invoke /opt/ros/diamondback/ros/bin/rospack deps-manifests bumblebee2
         [rospack] couldn't find dependency [libdc1394v2] of [bumblebee2]
        [rospack] missing dependency'
```

I tried to look for the package libdc1394v2 in ROS .. but I couldn't find a valid package that works for Diamondback version...

Does anyone know how I can solve this? Is there another package that I can use instead of libdc1394v2? Or do I have to re-install the C-turtle version of ROS?

-Divya

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11546/libdc1394-package-not-available-for-diamondback?/) by [Divya](https://answers.ros.org/users/1220/divya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2011-10-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `libdc1394v2` package has been deprecated for a very long time. It was long ago replaced by a `rosdep` dependency on the system version of `libdc1394`.

If you have a bumblebee driver that depends on `libdc1394v2`, it is not being actively maintained. You may be able to get it working by converting that `<depend>` to a `<rosdep>` in the `manifest.xml` file. But, I expect you will uncover other problems, beyond that.

There may not be any actively maintained bumblebee driver right now. It probably would not be terribly hard to create one, but a maintainer with access to the device would be necessary.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you have camera_drivers installed? Use

```
sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-camera-drivers
```

Since you are looking for libdc1394v2 I'm not sure it will work, but it definitely works for Point Grey Firewire cameras (Flea2) I have tried.

To use, [calibrate](http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera_calibration) your cameras using the stereo version command. That will save the calibration files to `/tmp`, but you can copy/move them into your node. In your launch file start up two [camera1394](http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera1394) nodes:

```
<!-- The left camera node. -->
<node
  pkg="camera1394" type="camera1394_node" name="camera_left">
  <rosparam file="$(find your_node)/left_bumblebee.yaml"/>
  <remap from="camera" to="left"/>
</node>

<!-- The right camera node. -->
<node
  pkg="camera1394" type="camera1394_node" name="camera_right">
  <rosparam file="$(find your_node)/right_bumblebee.yaml"/>
  <remap from="camera" to="right"/>
</node>
```

The `left_bumblebee.yaml` file will contain something like the following, where you set parameters for the [camera1394](http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera1394) node:

```
# ID of your camera. Use coriander to help identify.
guid: 0000000000000000
# Mode describes the size and number of channels for the images.
#video_mode: 640x480_mono8
video_mode: 320x240_yuv422
# The frame_id MUST be part of your URDF to display correctly in RViz.
frame_id: left_camera
# The location of the ROS calibration file.
camera_info_url: file:///absolute_path_to_your_node/calibration_file.yaml
# Frames per second.
frame_rate: 30
# Try to reset the camera when opening.
reset_on_open: true
```

These two nodes will then publish on `/left/image_raw`, `/left/image_rect`, `/right/image_raw`, and `/right/image_rect`. You can see all of the topics they publish on using `rxtopic list`. Many ROS stereo nodes require exact matches for the timestamps on the `image` and `camera_info` topics. You might get that with the bumblebee camera automatically. If not, you can try to run your images through something like [sync_images](http://ibotics.ucsd.edu/stingray/browser/trunk/sync_images).

Last thing: it would benefit you quite a bit to move at least to Diamondback, if not Electric. I don't think that C-turtle is going to be supported much longer, and there have been changes made recently that break some backwards compatibility. In any case, more people will be able to help you with Diamondback and Electric if you run into trouble.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2011-10-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Divya](https://answers.ros.org/users/1220/divya/) on 2011-11-02**:
hmm... okay.. I shall try that then!

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2011-11-02**:
In general, you really do have to calibrate cameras (quite often) to get decent results. The Bumblebee is different from what I have used before, but my guess is you need to separate out left and right images and publish them, then run the stereo calibration node.

**Comment by [Divya](https://answers.ros.org/users/1220/divya/) on 2011-11-01**:
@thomas- I have another silly question, do we really need to do this calibration stuff to get the rectified images from bumblebee? the calibration process seems to involve a big checker board etc..  Is there any other way I could get rectified images/calibrate images?

**Comment by [Divya](https://answers.ros.org/users/1220/divya/) on 2011-10-31**:
thank you guys! I finally managed to get the libdc1394 package downloaded!

**Comment by [Andreu](https://answers.ros.org/users/932/andreu/) on 2011-10-20**:
Completly right joq ! that is what we've learned this week ! Thanks !

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-10-19**:
`camera1394` will not work as suggested here. The bumblebee is a single 1394 camera that returns interleaved data for both left and right images. It needs a special driver.

**Comment by [Andreu](https://answers.ros.org/users/932/andreu/) on 2011-10-18**:
Thanks Thomas for the interest. When I'll get something clearer about the bumblebee2 i'll post it.

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2011-10-17**:
Do you get any errors if you run with just a single camera? Or if you decrease the resolution?

**Comment by [Andreu](https://answers.ros.org/users/932/andreu/) on 2011-10-17**:
As a result, I'm getting two "libdc errors": "libdc1394 error: Error: Failed to allocate iso bandwidth" and "libdc1394 error: Error: Failed to setup DMA capture".

**Comment by [Andreu](https://answers.ros.org/users/932/andreu/) on 2011-10-17**:
I'm also interested on acquiring images from bumblebee2. Thomas' answer is useful but I've to add the following to each node: . However initially I don't have calibration files , so can I run it without calibration file ?

However,

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2011-10-14**:
I've edited my answer to hopefully make it more clear as to what I think will work for you.

**Comment by [Divya](https://answers.ros.org/users/1220/divya/) on 2011-10-13**:
so you mean to say that instead of bumblebee2 package I should try to use 'camera-drivers'?